# Unity Resolution is not properly working on my device

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently testing my Unity game on my mobile device using USB debugging, but for some reason, the game appears stretched out on the screen. Please refer to these pictures for clarification.

Game window on unity editer

[image]

this is how it looks on my device

[image]

i tried everthing, but it's not working out....

Comment: sounds like your canvas scaler is wrong

Comment: how can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

First order of business is to ensure that the `Resolution` setting in `Project Settings > Editor > Unity Remote` is set to `Normal` and NOT `Downsize`.

Then ensure that your `Canvas Renderer` will actually scale how you want it to when translated to your mobile device's resolution.

When the `Canvas Renderer` is set to `Scale With Screen Size` and `Match Width or Height` is selected, then this can cause certain UI elements to stretch with different aspect ratios if not configured properly.

FYI, the two images you shared are identical on my side. NOt sure if you checked that you posted the right ones.